# How can I create a new asset source?

Tags: assets, sources, assets-field

Now I have a "gallery image" field which allows users to upload multiple images, and some "single-upload image field" in matrix block.

For "single-upload image field", I want to force users to choose images only from the "gallery image" field.

To do that, I want to create a custom asset source called "gallery image". So with this source selected, I can limit the source of "single-upload image field".

Any idea to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just create a new asset source (settings > volumes > new volume) 
then in your image field select 'Restrict uploads to a single folder' in your field and then select the asset source you just created.

[image]

Comment: Basically what you mean is to create a Asset field which source is based on another volume. But what I need is a new Asset field type and its source is another Asset field in the same entry.

Let's say when a user open a entry editing page, he selected three images to field A, Ctrl+s to save. Then he can only select these three images to field B.